# MongoDB store count in document vs perform count query

Tags: mongodb

After deciding to store comments in a separate collection from their corresponding posts, how do you store and return the number of comments per post?

Option 1: Update the counter on every insert of a new comment document (MongoDB doesn't support transactions though);
Option 2: Count the number of comments on retrieval of every post.
Option 3: ???

The case is the rendering of a collection of posts, where each should display the number of comments.

Comment: Related https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/use-cases/storing-comments/

Comment: Also, if using Mongoose then [populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) is the way to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) aggregation (analog for JOIN in RDBMS).

But actually I do not see a point to use the RDB schema in NoSQL DB. You must try to avoid the joins in NoSQL, because it is impacts the performance and goes against whole logic of the NoSQL.

P.S. the data duplication in the NoSQL is aceptable (-;

Comment: Storing and incrementing the count on number of comments seems to be a viable option, however by lack of transaction I cannot guarantee that incrementing the counter will actually result in insertion of the comment. Performing the lookup / count seems too much overhead for having the simple counter. Therefore the dilemma...

Comment: If you need transactions then why you do not use RDBMS (like MySQL/MariaDB, PostgreSQL, etc.)?

Comment: Because NodeJS / MongoDB seems overall a good choice for our live app.

Comment: NodeJS can use MySQL also (-;  Over all you can't have everything (performance, consistency, etc.). The perfect DB do not exist, so you must accept some trade offs (choose the DB which is mostly meets your needs or combine a few DB).

Comment: Yeah there's some things to consider, I'll think it over. Thanks!